# In construction grammar, is extraction a property of the construction or a separate construction?

Tags: syntax, questions, coordination, construction-grammar

I have a question regarding the notion of 'construction' in construction grammar. When a construction, say a coordination or a prepositional phrase or something, allows or doesn't allow extraction, is that property of allowing or not allowing extraction part of the properties of the construction?

So for instance with coordination and across-the-board extraction, is it correct under construction grammar to say that (1) realises a coordinate construction X-AND-Y and one of its properties is that parallel extraction is allowed across-the-board from within all conjuncts? Or are (1) and (2) just completely different constructions?

(1) Alex both makes extreme cakes and eats extreme cakes.

(2) Which cakes does Alex both make and eat?

Mainly, I'm confused about whether wh-questions are linked to declarative statements in construction grammar. In generative grammar (broadly) wh-questions are derived from the structure of the declarative statement, i.e. (2) is derived using the underlying structure of (1) as the base form, meaning that the availability of (2) is a property of the structure of (1), i.e. the two are linked. How is this link handled in construction grammar? Or are (1) and (2) simply viewed as completely different constructions?